# How can I sort out Xephyr's keyboard mapping?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xorg, x-server, xephyr

When I start up Xephyr inside of X, my keyboard map becomes wonky mostly just for non-printing characters. I can't use arrow keys. According to xev, The down arrow gets mapped to Super_R. The up arrow is Print Screen. PgDown is mapped to "Menu". My keyboard works fine in the original X display (:0), but in the Xephyr subdisplay (:1), nothing else quite works right.

I don't have any funky xmodmap things going on in my main X display that I'm aware of. All I really do is `setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps`.

Comment: You're not using SSH, right? Or in other words: you're using the exact same keyboard and X server with Xephyr like you use without it? And any better results when using the older `Xnest`? I don't know how that knowledge will help you, but maybe it does. ;-)

Comment: Yep. no ssh. Same keyboard and server. I'll try Xnest.

Comment: Xnest did the same thing, but at least it pointed me to the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [Bug 19365](http://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19365) which solved my problem:

Starting Xnest / Xephyr with -kb.

Comment: And no more need for `xmodmap` either, I hope? Good find!

Comment: (I think you can accept your own answer after 48 hours? Please come back to do so. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

The -kb option doesn't work in Ubuntu 10.04. Here's what worked for me:

`Xephyr -keybd ephyr,,,xkbmodel=evdev -ac -screen 800x600 -br -reset -terminate :1`

Comment: There's no need for all the empty commas, just list keyboard options as needed. In my case it is `-keybd ephyr,xkbmodel=evdev,xkblayout='de(nodeadkeys)'`

Answer (score 1):

After more unsuccessful googling, `man setxkbmap` finally pointed me into an easier solution:

> USING WITH xkbcomp
>
> If you have an Xserver and a client shell running on different  computers and XKB configuration files on those machines are different you can get problems specifying a keyboard map by model, layout, options names.[...] You can  solve  this problem by running the xkbcomp on the client side too.[..]
>   For example, the command
>
> **setxkbmap us -print | xkbcomp - $DISPLAY**
>
> makes both steps run on the same (client) machine and loads a  keyboard map into the server.

That is,

- launch Xephyr:

  ```
  Xephyr -ac -reset -screen 800x600 -retro :50 &
  ```

  (no need to provide keyboard info)
- and configure the new xsession:

  ```
  setxkbmap de -print | xkbcomp - :50
  ```

  (you need to know your keyboard layout)

Note: `setxkbmap` is your friend, and from [version 1.2.0](http://www.mail-archive.com/xorg-announce@lists.freedesktop.org/msg01183.html) the useful `-query` option is available to help you troubleshooting your keyboard (see [the corresponding patch log](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2009-October/002685.html)).

Comment: In [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/209433/xephyr-keyboard-layout/273611#273611) I indicate how to launch Xephyr to have it properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run `xkbcomp $DISPLAY :1` in X session in which Xephyr was started. This command will copy keyboard map from current server to your newly created. I use it like this:

```
Xephyr -screen 800x600 :1 > /dev/null &
sleep 2 && xkbcomp $DISPLAY :1
DISPLAY=":1" ./runcommand
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setxkbmap -model evdev -print | xkbcomp :100 :200
```

If you use Xephyr with xpra and you have incorrect keyboard map. If you see strange situation: Down key worked as enter (down arrow as break line), up arrow not working - use that command for set true xkb map.

:100 - Display number with control of xpra

:200 - Display number control of Xephyr

May be that command help, if you use x2go and mate desktop environment (if x2go settings keyboard on client turned off)

Comment: Please explain what this code does—this isn't very helpful as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not using SSH for this, right? Still, the following might get you started; it's what I scribbled down to troubleshoot keyboard issues when using `ssh -Y`:

You can save the current keyboard mapping (when not running Xephyr) using:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/my_xmodmap
```

Then, in Xephyr, you could try to explicitly load that:

```
xmodmap ~/my_xmodmap
```

And using `xev` you can monitor keyboard events. That probably won't help much by itself, but might help you Googling more helpful articles as that command is sometimes mentioned in such articles.

Comment: That makes some other keys work, but not all.

xev claims, for example that the keypad slash is XF86_Ungrab, not KP_Divide as it is defined in the xmodmap file I've dumped and used.

Answer (score 0):

For me (using german keyboard), it only works the combination of the previous solution pointed by [Arjan](https://superuser.com/users/482/arjan) together with the solution pointed by [panzi](https://superuser.com/users/55172/panzi) in [Xephyr keyboard layout](https://superuser.com/q/209433/77252), that is:

Start Xephyr:

```
Xephyr -keybd ephyr,,,xkbmodel=evdev,xkblayout=de -ac -reset -screen 800x600 -retro :1 &
```

Save current keyboard mapping and start an xterm loading the mapping:

```
xmodmap -pke > /tmp/my_modmap ; xterm -display :1 -ls -e "xmodmap /tmp/my_modmap; bash" &
```

Xephyr server: `xserver-xephyr 2:1.9.5-1`

Thanks to the original posters!

Comment: I found a better solution: see my [other answer](http://superuser.com/questions/70428/how-can-i-sort-out-xephyrs-keyboard-mapping/273603#273603) to this question.